# Predicting class label for single image in image classification

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, neural-network, object-detection, gesture-recognition

I am designing a Static Hand Gesture Recognition using deep learning neural networks.
I started with this implementation on kaggle - https://www.kaggle.com/ranjeetjain3/deep-learning-using-sign-langugage/notebook#Sign-Language.
The accuracy of this looks very high, but when I try predictions for custom images, I am getting wrong results. As a newbie, I doubt my interpretation and need help for it.

Below is my code with prediction:

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

# Read Images 
infer_image = mpimg.imread('D:\\Mayuresh\\DL using SL MNIST\\input\\infer\\7.png') 
plt.imshow(infer_image) 

# Resizing before the prediction
infer_image = np.resize(infer_image, (28,28,1))
infer_image_arr = np.array(infer_image)
infer_image_arr = infer_image_arr.reshape(1,28,28,1)

# Prediction
y_pred = model.predict_classes(infer_image_arr)
print(y_pred)

# Dictionary for translation
my_dict2 = {
    0: 'a',
    1: 'b',
    2: 'c',
    3: 'd',
    4: 'e',
    5: 'f',
    6: 'g',
    7: 'h',
    8: 'i',
    9: 'k',
    10: 'l',
    11: 'm',
    12: 'n',
    13: 'o',
    14: 'p',
    15: 'q',
    16: 'r',
    17: 's',
    18: 't',
    19: 'u',
    20: 'v',
    21: 'w',
    22: 'x',
    23: 'y'
}

my_dict2[int(y_pred)]
```

Can someone suggest changes needed or a snippet to predict the hand gesture for one image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you didn't train anything for your project and use neural network weights given in the Kaggle site.

> The accuracy of this looks very high, but when I try predictions for custom images, I am getting wrong results.

It seems like the network you are using over-fitted to MNIST dataset. So when you give different image, it gives bad results.

What you should do is creating a gesture dataset which includes many cases, especially cases that you want to detect. Then you should train your network with this newly created dataset using present weights as initial  weights for your training. Your network should learn different gesture situations. The key point for increasing accuracy in your project is training your network with different gesture images that resemble your inference input.

Comment: I downloaded the MNIST data, used given CNN architecture on kaggle, trained the model but I observe same class predictions for all custom images (that have different gestures on a white background). So I was unsure if I have done something wrong in the predictions code?

If you suggest creating a custom dataset for american sign language, how many images per gesture will be give good performance according to you?

Comment: You must see class predictions for all images, this is the nature of the neural network you are using. What you should do is determining a threshold so that if prediction for a class is above than this threshold the prediction is valid otherwise it is useless. Neural network predicts class results for all picture that you fed it. You can adjust this threshold by considering the results. Therefore, observing a prediction result for a custom image doesn't mean your code is wrong, on the contrary it means you are doing right, but you should apply a threshold to results.

Comment: How many images per gesture question is a hard question to answer. It depends on the situation. It depends on what condition you want to use it? In which angle, in which viewpoint you want to detect? I think you should have at least 3-4 images for all angle and viewpoint combinations that you want to detect. The key point here is that you should have equal distribution of your cases in your dataset. There should not be very much 'A' and very less 'B' for example. All characters in the sign language should be exists fairly. If you have not enough data, you can use **Data Augmentation**.

Comment: Thank you for replies. I tried the predict_classes() and I think it works well but the prediction results are not good when I used the kaggle datasets and implementations (like https://www.kaggle.com/dansbecker/running-kaggle-kernels-with-a-gpu) but I struggled with accuracy. May be I have to create my own dataset.

Comment: Are there any strategic guidelines or rules when we develop a CNN? When to add Conv2D/dense layers, filter size, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a codebase where you can train your model on the dataset that you generate. Based on things like your background, light settings etc. That would be better than using a pre-trained model which is trained on the data from the different distribution

I would recommend using [this](https://github.com/samrudh/Gesture-detection) where you can start video feed and training images will be automatically taken for the gestures. You also can select the number of classes you want. That can improve your performance. Or else you can use the original code [Emojinator](https://github.com/akshaybahadur21/Emojinator) which can detect 13 hand gestures